# TypeScript How to access object defined in other class

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I have a project that uses Aurelia framework. I want to make global\static object that should be accessed across couple files. But when I try to access it from a different file it says that my object is undefined. Here is what it looks like:

FirstFile.ts

```
export function showA() {
    console.log("Changed a to " + a);
}
export var a = 3;

export class FirstFile {
    public ModifyA() {
        a = 7;
        showA();
    }
```

It says that a  = 7. Then I use it in other file like this.

SecondFile.ts

```
import FirstFile = require("src/FirstFile");
export class SecondFile {
    showA_again() {
        FirstFile.showA();
}
```

I execute showA_again() in my view file called SecondFile.html

```
<button click.trigger="showA_again()" class="au-target">Button</button>
```

When I click button, I see in console that variable "a" is still 3.
Is there any way to store variables between files?

Comment: And where do you call the ModifyA()? I can't see this method being called anywhere.

Comment: This is bad. Don't do this. Add a to the class itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you to inject `FirstFile` into `SecondFile`. Now your code has a smell of bad architecture.

To answer your question: probably you are looking for static ([playground sample](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=%0Aexport%20class%20FirstFile%20%7B%0A%09%0A%09static%20showA%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%09console.log(%22Changed%20a%20to%20%22%20%2B%20FirstFile.a)%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20static%20a%20%3D%203%3B%0A%09%0A%20%20%20%20public%20ModifyA()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FirstFile.a%20%3D%207%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FirstFile.showA()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aexport%20class%20SecondFile%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20showA_again()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FirstFile.showA()%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D))

```
export class FirstFile {

    static showA = function() {
        console.log("Changed a to " + FirstFile.a);
    }

    static a = 3;

    public ModifyA() {
        FirstFile.a = 7;
        FirstFile.showA();
    }
}

export class SecondFile {
    showA_again() {
        FirstFile.showA();
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer. There are other ways to do this, but I like this one.

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis Could you provide an example? It would be great to see other options.

Comment: probably not worth it, this is probably the best way